# Help with general power series concept

Tags: power-series

If f(x) is some general polynomial, what will the power series expansion of f(x) be. Is there a set rule for finding the power series of polynomials.

Comment: It is itself. A polynomial is a finite power series.

Answer (score 0):

A power series, following Wikipedia, is an infinite sum 
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n,
$$
where $a_n$ are the coefficients of the $n$-th term. If for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$ it holds that $a_m=0$ when $m\geq n$, and $a_n\neq 0$, then you obtain a polynomial of degree $n$.